# How to take the backup of a VM immediately using azurerm_backup_protected_vm terraform resource

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Am trying to take a backup of the Azure VM in the Recovery Service Vault using Terraform.

Backup is configured and Last Backup Status is Warning (Initial backup pending).

I would need take the backup of the VM immediately when the backup is configured.

```
Below is my code:-


resource "azurerm_recovery_services_vault" "vault" {
  name                = var.vaultname
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.rgname
  sku                 = "Standard"
  soft_delete_enabled = false
}
resource "azurerm_backup_policy_vm" "example" {
  name                = "test-recovery-vault-policy"
  resource_group_name = var.rgname
  recovery_vault_name = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.vault.name
  timezone = "UTC"
  backup {
    frequency = "Daily"
    time      = "23:00"
  }
  retention_daily {
    count = 10
  }
  retention_weekly {
    count    = 42
    weekdays = ["Sunday", "Wednesday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
  }

  retention_monthly {
    count    = 7
    weekdays = ["Sunday", "Wednesday"]
    weeks    = ["First", "Last"]
  }

  retention_yearly {
    count    = 77
    weekdays = ["Sunday"]
    weeks    = ["Last"]
    months   = ["January"]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_backup_protected_vm" "vm1" {
  resource_group_name = var.rgname
  recovery_vault_name = var.vaultname
  source_vm_id        = var.vm_id
  backup_policy_id    = azurerm_backup_policy_vm.example.id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Backup is configured and Last Backup Status is Warning (Initial backup**
> pending).

You will get this warning because as per official [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-first-look-arm) its already mentioned the same things.

> After enabling backup, an initial backup runs. You can start the
> initial backup immediately, or wait until it starts in accordance with
> the backup schedule.
>
> Until the initial backup completes, the Last backup status shows as
> Warning **(Initial backup pending)**.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.

Am looking for options to trigger the backup immediately once the backup is configured using terraform.